# .ipa file installing on some devices and not on others ..why?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift2

I am developing an iOS app , i have a very weird problem.Let me explain:
My app was getting installed and work properly on all my beta tester devices..however while adding AdMob feature i had to include Google framework files to make it work.Initially i tried using Cocoa Pods and even updated my Cocoa version to allow successful installation of google framework files in my project.But since i could not make it work i added all the required google framework files manually.

I tested the app and it is working fine.
But now i am stuck with very weird problem that this new .ipa file is getting properly installed on my device but not on any other beta testing devices.

No idea what i messed up.

Please suggest and help me to resolve this issue

Extra Info about development environment:
1>Swift development
2>Xcode version 8.1

Comment: may be you are not included the Udid in developer portal

Comment: I hope you are sure that you have all updated provisioning profile and UDIDs.....

Comment: Yes i have included proper UDID and all have checked the provisioning profile setting.

Comment: @VishalSharma what is your app's deployment target ? and your test device's os version ?

Comment: @Wolverine My deployment target is 9.3 and devices os version is 10.1, Note even my device os version is 10.1...and its working good there..but not working on client test devices....

Comment: @VishalSharma, please add UDID of your client test devices

Answer (score 0):

if it's not installing then primary thing is to check provisional profile that you have used is correct or not.

Do below things

Open package of .ipa and check p-list contain your device UUID or not.

if it contain then try to check log(Window->devices) from Xcode why this is happening.

Answer (score -2):

**Remove this line from code**

```
request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID,@"3c2ee022a3ecb0374f4ad681d0daadd467b7d844eee3" ]
```